# html email form multi attachment via phpmailer no composer question/issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am having trouble getting form to send attachments. It will either hang up or not send them and the error file shows nothing. Site is on a shared hosting server. The form works without attachments.

I am not a coder but i have searched this site and most of the information i have found refers to editing files created by composer which i am not using. Do I need to need to create a temp folder for the files before they are attached and if I do where do I define the path? The php code below is what I found for multiple attachments without composer and have been trying to adapt without success. Below is the code for attaching the file in the html form (I can post the entire html form if needed but since it works i did not see the need) and the php mail file any help would be appreciated.

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="lname">Attach File:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">          
        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="attachFile" name="attachFile[]" multiple="multiple">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comment">Message:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="sendEmail">Send Email</button>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';


$msg = ''; // start with a blank message
$msg .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n";
$msg .= 'City: ' . $_POST['city'] . "\n";
$msg .= 'State: ' . $_POST['state'] . "\n";
$msg .= 'Telephone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\n";
$msg .= 'Message: ' . $_POST['message'] . "\n";

if (array_key_exists('attachFile', $_FILES)) {
 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'mail.domain.com'; // SMTP server
    $mail->Username = 'form@domain.com';
    $mail->Password = 'password';
    $mail->setFrom ('form@domain.com');
    $mail->AddAddress ('user@domain.com');
    $mail->Subject = "Info Request";
    $mail->Body = $msg;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    #  $mail->Port = 465;
    for ($ct = 0, $ctMax = count($_FILES['attachFile']['tmp_name']); $ct < $ctMax; $ct++) {
        //Extract an extension from the provided filename
        $ext = PHPMailer::mb_pathinfo($_FILES['attachFile']['name'][$ct], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        //Define a safe location to move the uploaded file to, preserving the extension
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['attachFile']['name'][$ct])) . '.' . $ext;
        $filename = $_FILES['attachFile']['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachFile']['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            if (!$mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename)) {
                $msg .= 'Failed to attach file ' . $filename;
            }
        } else {
            $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
        }
    }
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        $msg .= 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        $msg .= 'Message sent!';
    }
}
# $return = $mail->Send();
?>
<html>
<head>
//<meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" Content="0;url=thankyou.html">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#366A7F">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Composer is irrelevant to this. Composer is just a way of including 3rd-party PHP files into your project more easily - it saves you some downloading and copying files. If you're looking for a solution to why your files don't attach properly to your emails, you can use any code which might help with that, regardless if composer was used to include anything into the script or not.

Comment: What output do you see? Do you realise you don't have `echo $msg;` anywhere? So you won't see any of the content you've put in there for debugging etc.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).